# Hibernate JPA : Can not set field x to x

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I have this **project** class :

```
@Entity
public class Project implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="id", unique=true )
private Long id;

@Column(name="name", nullable=false, unique = true)
private String name;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="projectid", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<Collaborator> collaborators = new HashSet<>();

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
}
```

and then **Collaborator** :

```
@Entity
public class Collaborator implements Serializable{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
private Long id;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(nullable = true)
private Project projectid;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
}


public Project getProjectid() {
    return projectid;
}

public void setProjectid(Project projectid) {
    this.projectid = projectid;
}
```

And In my DAO I want to excute this query :

```
@Query("select c from Collaborator as c where c.projectid = ?1 and  c.showable = true")
List<Collaborator> findAllShowableCollaboratorsByProjectidAndShowableTrue(Long projectId);
```

But I'm getting this error :

> Caused by: org.hibernate.property.access.spi.PropertyAccessException: Error accessing field [private java.lang.Long gestionprojet.java.entities.beans.Project.id] by reflection for persistent property [gestionprojet.java.entities.beans.Project#id] : 1
>       at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.GetterFieldImpl.get(GetterFieldImpl.java:71)
>       at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:224)
>       at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4647)
>       at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.isTransient(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4358)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.internal.ForeignKeys.isTransient(ForeignKeys.java:226)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.internal.ForeignKeys.getEntityIdentifierIfNotUnsaved(ForeignKeys.java:276)
>       at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.getIdentifier(EntityType.java:462)
>       at org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType.nullSafeSet(ManyToOneType.java:161)
>       at org.hibernate.param.NamedParameterSpecification.bind(NamedParameterSpecification.java:53)
>       at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.bindParameterValues(QueryLoader.java:628)
>       at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1956)
>       at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1909)
>       at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1887)
>       at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:932)
>       at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:349)
>       at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2615)
>       at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2598)
>       at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2430)
>       at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2425)
>       at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:502)
>       at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:371)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:216)
>       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1460)
>       at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1426)
>       at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1398)
>       at org.hibernate.Query.getResultList(Query.java:417)
>       at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:114)
>       at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:78)
>       at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:102)
>       at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:92)
>       at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:482)
>       at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:460)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>       at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>       at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
>       at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:280)
>       at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>       at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
>       ... 59 common frames omitted
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.Long field gestionprojet.java.entities.beans.Project.id to java.lang.Long
>       at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.get(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Unknown Source)
>       at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.GetterFieldImpl.get(GetterFieldImpl.java:67)
>       ... 98 common frames omitted

My environnement :

1. Hibernate core 5.2.3
2. mysql-connector-java 5.1.37
3. spring-jdbc4.3.2.RELEASE
4. spring-orm 4.3.2.RELEASE

I have tried rolling back hibernate t version 4 but still the same problem.

Any help would be appreciated.Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `projectid` in your `Collaborator` is a `Project` object, not a `Long` object. So change your repository method to:

```
@Query("select c from Collaborator as c where c.projectid.id = ?1 and  c.showable = true")
List<Collaborator> findAllShowableCollaboratorsByProjectidAndShowableTrue(Long projectId);
```

#### Suggestions:

- Note that using position param binding is not recommended because the order of the params cannot be changed (In your case it seems fine because there is only one param). I suggest that you change that:

  ```
  @Query("select c from Collaborator as c where c.projectid.id = :pid and  c.showable = true")
  List<Collaborator> findAllShowableCollaboratorsByProjectidAndShowableTrue(@Param("pid") Long pid);
  ```
- Using `projectid` as a field name with a type of `Project` is a bit confusing. Changing the name to something like `project` looks better.

Comment: Thank you for you response, and the suggestions. I have an other phenomenon : when I add data to a seperate 3 tables, the `id` of the row is incremented accordingly, example : if I add data to project `id = 1` and the in collaborator `id` will be equal to `2`. Any ideas ?

Comment: Sorry I do not quite understand your question. It is supposed to work like that since you specified auto-increment on the id fields of your entities if you are talking about why the id is incremented on insert.